# Profile picture suddenly changed on various Stack Exchange sites

Tags: bug, profile-picture, gravatar

My profile picture suddenly changed across multiple Stack Exchange sites.

My original (and desired) profile picture, [image: original/desired picture], still shows up on Stack Overflow [[link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh)], my network profile [[link](https://stackexchange.com/users/953149/ruakh)], and some other sites.

But a different profile picture, [image: different/undesired picture], suddenly shows up on various other sites, such as [[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/40627/ruakh?tab=profile)] and [[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/12378/ruakh)].

Needless to say, I didn't do this.

Why would this be?

Comment: It's a bug that affects accounts created prior to August 2013 which didn't use the newer system to upload a custom avatar.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog This also happened to me, and my account is only 5y 7m old.

Comment: So it's not the same bug. Reopening.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog: I've rolled back your edit -- sorry -- because I think it's confusing for the same question to use first-person pronouns (I/me/my/etc.) to refer to two different people. Also, it probably makes sense to wait till Monday, when the known case is expected to be fixed, to see if that fix also addresses these other similar cases.

Comment: @Sonic This is otherwise still the same issue. There was confirmation that the issue affected more than just accounts before that date: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409143/my-avatar-icon-has-reset-but-only-on-stack-overflow/409168#comment855193_409168

Comment: @animuson This was not noted in the copy of the question *here*, so I wasn't aware of it. It would be nice if it were noted in the copy here, so it would be a proper duplicate; at the moment, it isn't, since the answer there doesn't cover the case here.

Comment: Yay, my original profile picture is back!