# Profile Picture not consistent across network

Tags: bug, profile-page, profile-picture, information-display, gravatar

I was a bit shocked to find out my profile picture got somehow disappeared(?) in the other network. I checked on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Exchange and seems like only in Stack Overflow, it is correct.

This wasn't the case before, how did this happen? As far as I know, I have been using the same SSO login and email for all the sites. So Gravatar should show the same.

Here's a screenshot (with poorly hand-drawn red circles included):

[image: not same]

Here are the links for the same:

- [User Praveen Kumar Purushothaman - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/187488/praveen-kumar-purushothaman)
- [User Praveen Kumar Purushothaman - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/462627/praveen-kumar-purushothaman)
- [User Praveen Kumar Purushothaman - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/462627/praveen-kumar-purushothaman)

Is this a user error or a system error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Profile picture suddenly changed on various Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367525/profile-picture-suddenly-changed-on-various-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: There are a *lot* of duplicates for this one:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367525/profile-picture-suddenly-changed-on-various-stack-exchange-sites, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409164/13138080, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409143, etc.  Please search [SE](https://stackexchange.com) before posting another here, y'all ;)