# Inconsistent Identicon between main and meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, profile-picture, identicon

I was just browsing CGCC, and I went over to the meta, and noticed something strange: That's not the indenticon I've come to recognize. Somehow, my identicon changed sometime in the last day or two, *and only on Meta.* Across the entire network, my identicon on meta sites is different from my identicon on main sites.

There was recently [a bug with community's profile picture](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed), but this is a different bug. [As pointed out by caird coinheringaahing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367595/inconsistent-identicon#comment1224773_367595), this seems to be a new bug that just happened and is affecting any users, not just older users. Also, this is entirely to do with the identicon, not a gravatar profile picture, as in the other related bugs that [ollie mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367595/inconsistent-identicon#comment1224771_367595).

[image: My identicon on main]

[image: My identicon on meta]

---

Why did this happen, and more importantly, is this supposed to happen?

Comment: [Bug report about the Community user's identicon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367454/355458). 1 hour ago, it was supposedly [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367460/355458), so I suspect that fix broke things for other users

Comment: @Ollie No, this is a different bug. That only affected older users, and started a few days ago. This appears to affect newer users as well, and just happened. Also, it appears to only affect users with identicon profile pictures, not those with "custom" profiles

Comment: Also broken: [1](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king), [2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs), [3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/30688/feersum), [4](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15599/level-river-st). There are easily many more examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why has Community's profile picture changed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed)

Comment: @Rob [See caird's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367595/inconsistent-identicon-between-main-and-meta-sites?noredirect=1#comment1224773_367595) and the first edit of the question.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing & AaronMiller are you aware of [animuson's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367525/profile-picture-suddenly-changed-on-various-stack-exchange-sites#comment1224686_367525); it's not only users before a particular date, and he supports *that* duplicate link (as it's in the banner above that comment). --- Thanks for keeping us honest Aaron.

Comment: @Rob I think the biggest argument against the duplicate is the changes reported only seem to affect users with identicon profile pictures - the other one affected users with both identicon *and* custom profile pictures

Comment: @Rob The bug with the Community profile pic was also reported to have been fixed, which, as caird said, is likely to be what caused this issue.

Comment: cairdcoinheringaahing & AaronMiller while we *could* credit [aaron's comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367454/why-has-communitys-profile-picture-changed#comment1224785_367460) instead, then I guess I could take credit for the review (and not caving). --- I'll stick with "that's the correct duplicate target" (which has a complicated set of rules on MSE); especially in light of the [answer from Dean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367598/282094). 

Comment: Close voters: I can see the relation, but that question about the community profile is ***not a duplicate***.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well this is fun, metas typically inherit their parent site's details, but a profile image backfill ran for each site independently which means the calculation for a Gravatar works on the data in each site's database. There is a slight inconsistency between *some* main site and meta site users that meant the Gravatar calculation worked out different URLs between those two.

We're not going to run the backfill again but the synchronization problem will address itself in the next few hours when a reconciliation job runs. In fact, I'm going to force that job to run in a moment so this should be in a sane state shortly. Eventual consistency :)

Apologies for the mess here, there are a million moving pieces to this part of the system and, sadly, not all of them are documented.

**UPDATE** There have been a few problems with the synchronisation process that mean this is still in a somewhat bad state. We’re fixing those and will get things back in order on Monday. Sorry for the delay

Comment: I've just checked it on CGCC, and it seems to be fixed now. Thanks for the quick remediation!

Comment: Dean *whac-a-mole* Ward ...

Comment: Having a bad day? ;)

Comment: Is this [status-completed] now, then?

Comment: @bobble It's still going, has a lot of things to churn through

Comment: I believe this is related to this backfill - [this user](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95792/user)'s identicon appears to have been broken by this the other way around - their normal identicon shows up in the "change profile picture" screen but their picture has been altered to match a different identicon, which was previously visible on meta, on the main site as well.

Comment: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjEI0.png) is an image of the bug @hyper-neutrino mentioned. The blue one is my usual identicon, while this green-yellow one is new. The odd thing is that I signed up in 2019, so the salting thingy should have been implemented already, and I shouldn't need a new identicon.

Comment: @user looking into it, fix should be there shortly

Comment: @user apologies for the delay, this should be back to its previous state now.

Comment: @DeanWard It is, thanks!

Comment: @DeanWard - as of right now, I still show different icons on the main/meta sites I visit (tested Physics and Chemistry).

Comment: You're [not alone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367683/why-is-my-default-profile-picture-a-different-colour-on-site-metas) (a dupe from a couple of minutes ago.) @JonCuster

Comment: @ARogueAnt. - I'm starting to get a Dr. Jekyll and Mr. Hyde vibe now, switching from main to meta sites...

Comment: As of 7/28/2021 this is now resolved for me. Looks like the synchronization worked finally.

Comment: Should this still be [tag:status-planned], or is this now resolved network-wide?

Comment: @AaronMiller it’s resolved - changed to [tag:status-completed]. Thanks for the poke!