# Why is my (default) profile picture a different colour on site metas?

Tags: bug, design, profile-picture

On the meta-sites of stacks (the scifi.meta.stackexchange to the actual scifi.stackexchange) my profile picture (which is the one I got by default) has different colours to the one on the regular site.
Examples:
[image]
[image]

Why is this? Is it a bug?

(This is hardly something experience-breaking, of course, but I would like to know.)

Comment: Sorry there are no poorly-drawn red circles on the pictures!

Comment: Try doing some action on the meta site (vote, comment, etc) and it might "fix" the problem. (Not sure, hence only comment)

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMaskV2 - nope, that does fix the problem (tried it).